# MySQL last_insert_id() not working with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables which I am trying to add some data to. I am using jQuery/AJAX to send the data to a PHP file which processes it.

I want to get the auto-incremented ID of the first insert to table `messages` and then insert that ID into a second table, `messages_receiver_map`. When I try the following in PHPmyAdmin, it works fine, but it doesn't work with PHP:

```
...

if( !$errors ) {
    $mysqli->query("
        INSERT INTO `messages`(`senderid`,`sendername`,`messagesubject`, `messagecontent`, `messagetime`) values ('".$uid."', '".$sendername."', '".$inputvalues['messagesubject']."','".$inputvalues['messagecontent']."', '".$inputvalues['messagetime']."');
        SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO `message_receiver_map` (`messageid`, `receiverid`) VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, '".$inputvalues['messageto']."');
    ");
    $returnResult = "Success";      
}

...
```

Comment: By default `mysqli` cannot execute several queries.

Comment: And, why `jquery` is being tagged in this question?

Comment: @u_mulder So, should I just run two queries separately and use the saved variable?

Comment: @Bruno or try `mysqli_multi_query`

Comment: thanks, ill look into it :)

Comment: Might be simpler to do 2 seperate queries and use `$mysqli->insert_id` between the 2 queries

Comment: If it works fine in phpmyadmin, try to combine it to a stored procedure/routine, and in PHP, just call it with your parameters